# Is the file path the issue?

Tags: javascript, html, json, path

Something is wrong with this js and html, I keep getting errors. I am using 000webhost to try and get it to work, but that's not working either. I get these errors through google developer tools. I don't want to use a python http.server for a local host and would like to just use the local files on the computer. Here is the full json file path "C:\Users\Heather\Documents\Ben Black - IT 4990\CuraScript ICD-10-CM Front-end Database\data.json". Am I wrong for putting it as "data.json"? If I put the entire file path for json in there, wouldn't it inhibit the others from accessing the html when it is shared as a zip folder for them to store on their local computer files?

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading
> 'addEventListener')
> at script.js:39:41 (anonymous) @ script.js:39 icd10cm-codes-2024.html:1 Access to fetch at
> 'file:///C:/Users/Heather/Documents/Ben%20Black%20-%20IT%204990/CuraScript%20ICD-10-CM%20Front-end%20Database/data.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin
> requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data,
> isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.
> script.js:7
>
> ```
>    GET file:///C:/Users/Heather/Documents/Ben%20Black%20-%20IT%204990/CuraScript%20ICD-10-CM%20Front-end%20Database/data.json
> ```
>
> net::ERR_FAILED loadJSON @ script.js:7 load (async) (anonymous) @
> script.js:37 script.js:13 TypeError: Failed to fetch
> at loadJSON (script.js:7:3) (anonymous) @ script.js:13 Promise.catch (async) loadJSON @ script.js:12 load (async) (anonymous)
> @ script.js:37

```js
/*eslint-env es6*/
// Global variable to store the loaded JSON data
let jsonData = [];

// Function to load the JSON data
function loadJSON() {
  fetch("data.json")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
    jsonData = data;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}

// Function to filter and display the JSON data
function search() {
  const searchInput = document.getElementById('search-input').value;
  const outputArea = document.getElementById('output-area');

  // Filtering the JSON data based on the search query
  const filteredData = jsonData.filter(item => item.name.includes(searchInput));

  // Clearing the output area
  outputArea.innerHTML = '';

  // Displaying the filtered data
  filteredData.forEach(item => {
    const resultElement = document.createElement('p');
    resultElement.textContent = item.name;
    outputArea.appendChild(resultElement);
  });
}

// Load JSON data when the page loads
window.onload = loadJSON;
// Event listener for search button click
document.getElementById('search-button').addEventListener('click', search);
// Event listener for search button click
  const searchButton = document.getElementById('search-button');
  if (searchButton) {
    searchButton.addEventListener('click', search);
  }
```

```css
body{
    background-color: lightblue;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
.content-wrapper{
    padding: 10px 30px;
}
p{
    text-align: justify;
}
h1{
    text-align: center;
}
.highlight{
    font-weight: 700;
    color: forestgreen;
}
h1, h2{
    font-weight: 400;
}

ul li{
    list-style-type: square;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>ICD-10 Code and Description Search</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css"/>
  
</head>
<body onload="loadJSON()">
    <h1>ICD-10 Code/Description Search</h1>
    <input type="text" id="search-input" placeholder="Enter code or description">
    <button onclick="search()">Search</button>
    <div id="output-area"></div>
    
    <script src="data.json"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Many browsers do not like to "fetch" a local file from the file system. If it 
If the file is in the same or under the folder where the HTML file is, then use relative addressing or address it from the root of the web folder but you MUST be on a server
Press F12 and look in the network tab to see what it tells you

Comment: your search buttons doesn't have an ID on it so that's why this fails: `document.getElementById('search-button').addEventListener('click', search);`

Comment: And the second error is what I mentioned. Fetch does not allow file:// protocol. The file needs to instead not be JSON but an actual script. Simply do this: 1. rename it data.js, 2. in that file change `{ ... }` to `const data = { ... }` and now you can use the object

Comment: The error "Access to fetch at 'file:///' has been blocked by CORS policy" suggests that you are facing a CORS issue due to the local file system. To avoid this, you can use a simple server to serve your files locally. For example, you can use live-server or http-server to serve your files.

Comment: @AhmedAliRajput Then she cannot just send a zip file to ppl

Answer (score 0):

Fetch does not allow file:// protocol. The file needs to instead not be JSON but an actual script. You already have `<script src="data.json"></script>` so simply do this:

1. rename it data.js,
2. in that file change `{ ... }` to
   `const data = { ... }` and now you can use the object called data.

Lastly about naming. JSON is a string. When it is parsed it is an object. jsonData is not a good name for the variable that holds an object and not a string